# Codeigniter Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, login

Hace poco comencé a desarrollar una aplicación utilizando CodeIgniter y me surgió el siguiente problema:

Tengo un formulario de logueo que forma parte de una barra de navegación, la idea es que si el usuario indica datos de logueo erróneos, un mensaje de error se imprima y avise cual es el problema; para tal efecto estoy utilizando la librería form_validation que el framework posee.

Sin embargo, la pestaña se recarga y no muestra ningún mensaje de error. Líneas abajo el código que estoy utilizando.

View:

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'index/login' ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        echo validation_errors(); // Mensajes de error
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="tbx_username">Nombre de usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tbx_username" id="tbx_username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="tbx_password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="tbx_password" id="tbx_password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tbx_username', 'Usuario', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tbx_password', 'Contraseña', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $username = $this->input->post('tbx_username');
            $password = $this->input->post('tbx_password');

            if($username == 'admin' && $password == '12345')
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
            }
        }            
        redirect('/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme a solucionar mi problema, o me indique si el camino que estoy siguiendo es el correcto.

Gracias.

Comment: y que hace la funcion `validation_errors()`, de todas maneras, haga lo que haga, en el controller solo dice que volverá a refrescar la pagina `/index`, por tanto no deberia mostrar ningun mensaje

Comment: tengo entendido que a la vista que cargues, en el caso de que haya un error, en ves de ocupar un redirect, podrias llamar una vista con parametros donde uno de elos deba ser el mensaje de error, aqui la documentacion de codeigniter https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: @jolsalazar gracias por tu respuesta. El problema se encontraba en el redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de mis comentarios, podrías usar `session` `flash_data`.

Prueba este código.

Controller

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tbx_username', 'Usuario', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tbx_password', 'Contraseña', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $username = $this->input->post('tbx_username');
            $password = $this->input->post('tbx_password');

            if($username == 'admin' && $password == '12345')
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensaje', 'Usuario o contraseña incorrecto');
            }
        }            
        redirect('/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

View

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'index/login' ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        // se muestra el mensaje de error
        $mensaje = $this->session->flashdata('mensaje');
        echo $mensaje;
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="tbx_username">Nombre de usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tbx_username" id="tbx_username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="tbx_password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="tbx_password" id="tbx_password" placeholder="Contraseña" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Las sessiones flash, como su nombre dice, solo se mantienen hasta la siguiente petición. (osea de momento)

Documentación: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.